# R create JSON in R

Tags: r, rjson

I want to get to get the values from this JSON string: `{ "item": [ {  "value": 142 } , { "value": 200 } ] }`

R code:

```
library(rjson)
item <- list(item=c(value= 142,value=200))
toJSON(item)
```

And I have:

```
> toJSON(item)
[1] "{\"item\":{\"value\":142,\"value\":200}}"
```

How do I get the values from the json string in R?

Comment: Does `item` _have_ to be in that structure or can you do something like what @cory suggests in his answer. Also, you should show a `library(rjson)` in your question text even if you have it as a tag. There are a plethora of JSON packages for R.

Answer (score 1):

Discussion of `I()` and what it does is in the `RJSONIO` documentation, but that's what you are looking for...

```
library("RJSONIO")
item <- list(item=I(list(list(value= 142),list(value=200))))
> toJSON(item)
[1] "{\n \"item\": [\n {\n \"value\":    142 \n},\n{\n \"value\":    200 \n} \n] \n}"
```